# Regular expression to higlight a word in a text

Tags: javascript, regex

I wand to highlight the word used to perform a research. I am trying to use a regular expression in JavaScript, but I am getting the following issue.

This is the code that I am using :

```
var key_word = "and"; 
var text= "I bought milk and water"; 
var re = new RegExp("(" + key_word + ")", 'ig'); 
text = text.replace(re, "<strong>$1</strong>"); 
console.log(text);
```

Correct Result :

```
I bought milk <strong>and</strong> water.
```

But with the text

```
var text = "I am getting a better understanding.";
```

Wrong Result :

```
I am getting a better underst<strong>and</strong>ing.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + key_word + ")\\b", 'ig');
```

Using word boundaries - `\b` will ensure that keyword is only matched when it is preceded and followed by a non-word character.

Note, while using `RegExp` constructor, you need to escape the backslash. So, it should be `\\b`, because `\` is itself an escape character in string literal.

---

Or, you can use regex literal:

```
var re = /\b(and)\b/ig;
text = text.replace(re, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

Comment: @GiuseppePes. Ah! You need to double escape the `\` in RegExp constructor. Try it now.

Comment: What if I want to use in the keyword special characters like `*` or `.`?

Comment: @GiuseppePes. Just use them as it is, if you want them as quantifier. It you want to use `*` literally, escape them, or use character class - `[*]`